# Angular add theme scss to override global style

Tags: css, angular

I am using Angular 7. All my global styles are in style.scss file.
I also have 2 themes: dark.scss and light.scss. Those 2 files are on path:

```
assets/css/dark.scss
assets/css/light.scss
```

I tried to include those themes in my application in 2 ways:

1) I added theme styles in angular.json::

```
styles: [
     "src/styles.scss",       
     "src/assets/css/light.scss",
     "src/assets/css/dark.scss"             
],
```

2) I imported them in styles.scss file:

```
@import 'assets/css/light.scss';
@import 'assets/css/dark.scss';
```

I tried this import at the beginning of the style.scss and also at the end of the style.scss,

What ever I tried, my theme file.scss is overridden with style.scss. Angular somehow put theme.scss before style.scss in style order. Is there any way that my theme style override style.scss ?

Comment: if you import them at the beginning of `styles.scss` file CSS will, naturally, override them. which kind of CSS rules are you setting? are you sure that `light.scss` or `dark.scss` are just not strong as `styles.scss` ones?

Comment: If I import on at the begging it is clear, if I import at the end, the same result, that is weird. Default css rules are applied in angular, I did not change anything. "are you sure that light.scss or dark.scss are just not strong as styles.scss ones?" I do not know what you exactly meant with this sentence ?

Comment: I mean, if you have something like `body { background-color: black; }` inside `dark.scss` and `body.wrapper { background-color: white; }` inside `styles.scss` this will be always be the one which is getting read, nevermind which order is the `.scss` being included

Comment: @CapitanFindus your comment here seems to be interesting and probably true for my case. Can you please add this as an answer with a bit longer explanation how I can accept it. Or add some reference also for this kind of problem or for theming.

Comment: sorry about late response, did you figure it out already? if not, could you please a few of your CSS code?